# Puzzling statement about implication in Gries and Schneider

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm reading [*A Logical Approach to Discrete Math* by David Gries and Fred B. Schneider](http://a.co/2knGwPr) and I got all snagged up on an apparent contradiction on an elementary point. On page 35, they write:

> For example, consider the sentence "If you don't eat your spinach, I'll spank you". Using variable $es$ for "you eat your spinach" and variable $sy$ for "I'll spank you", we translate this as $\neg{es}\;\Rightarrow\;{sy}$. Note that this expression is *true* if you eat your spinach, i.e., if $\neg{es}$ is *false* then so is $\neg{es}\;\Rightarrow\;{sy}$.

The statement "This expression is *true* if you eat your spinach" should mean that

$$\neg{es}\;\Rightarrow\;{sy}$$

is *true* if $\neg{es}$ is *false*. That means $es$ is *true* and the implication is *true* no matter what the value of $sy$ because the implication is equivalent to $es\vee{sy}$. If you eat your spinach, then you may still get spanked, or not. This looks right to me.

The author's next phrase seems to contradict that: "if $\neg{es}$ is *false* then so is $\neg{es}\;\Rightarrow\;{sy}$". Huh?

Is there some meta-level on which I should be interpreting that last (seemingly incorrect) phrase, or is this just a typo? I'm asking this question because the contradiction is so blaring and blatant that a typo doesn't seem plausible in this place.

Comment: You are correct.